# Entity query on custom entity is not checking access rights

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom entity called project_member. Not all user have access to this entity. But when I query this entity with entityQuery as follows
`\Drupal::entityQuery('project_member')->execute()`
all the entities are returning. It is not checking the access rights. I am missing anything. I tried to implement hook_project_member_access() to restrict the access still entityQuery is not checking those access results.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement `hook_query_ENTITY_TYPE_access_alter`  ( `hook_query_project_member_access_alter`) to apply the custom query access check.

For example https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_query_node_access_alter/8.9.x

You might need to `$query->addTag(‘project_member_access’)` but from memory that tag may now be added automatically by the entity query handler.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.

Comment: Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Query adds the access tag; 

It's been there for a while, but here's a link to 11.x branch https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/11.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Query.php?ref_type=heads#L143

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, entity queries will respect access if you've got the appropriate access tag on the query, which you may or may not be defining. I haven't dug much into how to implement this as custom entities, but the node module defines the `node_access` query tag that's automatically applied to all node entity queries (I believe), so that would be a good place to start looking.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/group/node_access/8.9.x